# Как заставить android studio сделать так, что бы он обновлял пред. версии приложений?

Tags: android, android-studio

Был фрилансер программист, который сделал задачку для корпоративных пользователей.

Сейчас появилась задача дополнить проект, корректировки в код я внес, все отрабатывает, но когда я создаю арк и устанавливаю на телефон, он выводит предупреждение + не может найти пред. версию приложения. Как говорит фрилансер , он не использовал подпись для приложения. Но в проекте , если зайти в меню подписи арк, там был ссылка на jks, если я указываю этот jks , то все равно все без изменений.

Вопрос - что нужно сделать, что бы приложение обновлялось (сейчас оно не обновляется с пред. версии, говорит конфликт пакетов)

p.s. Если я проверяю на наличие подписи пред. файлов, то там ее действительно нет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: возможно он использовал другой JKS. в любом случае, я бы рекомендовал вам создать новый ключ и оставить его в проекте с паролями в проекте. да, заказчик может быть недоволен, но проблема на стороне старого разраба (додуматься же надо еще, отдавать неподписанные релизные сборки)

Comment: понял, но если я создаю подпись через андроид студио, то ошибка все равно сохраняется =( Я же так делаю?    Build - generate singled bundle or apk - apk - create new

Comment: да, так. ошибка и будет, т.к. ключи разные. а как вы создаете апк БЕЗ подписи?

Comment: Я сделал проверку и понял что арк не подписывается =(    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.4\bin>keytool -printcert -jarfile C:\Driver\app\debug\app-debug.apk
Not a signed jar file                                                                                                                                                                    Как тогда правильно создавать подпись или подписать уже существующей?

Comment: keytool может показать только подпись v1, которая используется в старых версиях Андроида. Новую подпись можно пощупать с помощью apksigner: https://developer.android.com/tools/apksigner. Не подписанное приложение установить в принципе нельзя - установщик откажется это делать. У вас же вылазит плей-защита, которая срабатывает на сертификат разработчика, который никогда не публиковался в GP - тут только жать "Всё равно установить" или публиковать аппу в GP. Для успешного обновления должен совпадать сертификат подписи и пакет (applicationId) и номер версии не ниже установленной.